# React Navigation 5: Switching between different stack navigators in React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm finding difficulty in digesting the official documentation and I'm stuck finding out a solution to move between different stack navigators. I have provided my current implementation and code snippet to explain my problem better.

I have a bottom tab navigator and 2 stack navigators to handle different use cases.

```
BottomNavigation.js
StackNavigation.js
AuthStackNavigation.js
```

I have created multiple stack navigators within `StackNavigation.js` and rendering each StackNavigators within `BottomNavigation.js`

```
***StackNavigation.js***

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={ScreenLogo}>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={Home} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

const ProfileStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={ScreenLogo}>
            <Stack.Screen name="MahaExpo" component={Profile} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export { HomeStackNavigator, ProfileStackNavigator };
```

And as I said I'm rendering each navigator inside tab navigator to switch between screens.

```
 ***BottomNavigation.js***

import { HomeStackNavigator, ProfileStackNavigator } from '../Navigations/StackNavigation'

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function BottomNavigation() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home" >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeStackNavigator}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="ProfileStackNavigator"
                component={ProfileStackNavigator}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default BottomNavigation
```

and I'm rendering this within app.js and inside NavigationContainer. I have created AuthStackNavigation.js which has a login and register screens.

```
***AuthStackNavigation.js***

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthStackNavigation = ({ }) => (

    <AuthStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
        <AuthStack.Screen name="UserLogin" component={UserLogin}></AuthStack.Screen>
        <AuthStack.Screen name="UserRegister" component={UserRegister}></AuthStack.Screen>
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
);

export default AuthStackNavigation
```

So currently, I'm showing the home screen with some public content and user can switch to different screens using the bottom tab navigator linked to different screens. When the user clicks on profile tab, im displaying a button to login which should take the user to ***AuthStackNavigation.js*** which has a login and register screen. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
const ProfileStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={ScreenLogo}>
            <Stack.Screen name="MahaExpo" component={Profile} />
            <Stack.Screen name="UserLogin" component={UserLogin} />
            <Stack.Screen name="UserRegister" component={UserRegister} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

on profile page  check user is logged in or not, if not, simply navigate to UserLogin screen. Once login simply pop back to profile page are refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to do this with the click of a button on the user profile page

Comment: you have to implement a function to check login and put it in button onclick

Comment: yes, I'm already adding a button if the user is logged in but my doubt is how do I navigate to the login screen present within AuthStackNavigation by clicking that button

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate('UserLogin');, you dont need AuthStackNavigation,

Comment: I tried this but I was getting exception saying no routes defined

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of communicating between two separate navigators if they're not related to each other (one is a child navigator of another or etc.), unless you create something like RootStackNavigator, which would be on the higher level and which would contain all the navigators you have listed above.
Create guest navigators array, authorized navigators array and some shared routes (if needed). Guest navigator contains authstack only and authorized one contains other navigators, if you use redux, context or something like this you can check for the token on startup to determine which navigator you have to use. Logging in will give you the token and will automatically change your navigator to authorized navigators and logging out will throw you back (as you no longer have the token) to the guest navigators which will contain only authentication flow.

Pretty hard to explain ;) hope this helps..

**Redux Example**

```
`
const authNavigators = [
{
type: "screen",
key: "authNavigators",
name: "authNavigators",
component: authNavigators,
},
];

const otherNavigators = [
{
type: "screen",
key: "otherNavigators1",
name: "otherNavigator1",
component: otherNavigators1,
},
{
type: "screen",
key: "otherNavigators2",
name: "otherNavigator2",
component: otherNavigators3,
},
...
];

const RootStack = () => {

  const { condition } = useSelector(
  (state) => state.store);

 let navigators = otherNavigators;

 if(condition) {
  navigators = authNavigators;
  }

 return (
 <RootStackNavigator.Navigator>
  {navigators.map((item) => {
    return (
      <RootStackNavigator.Screen
        {...item}
        options={({ route: { params } }) => ({
          ...item.options,
        })}
      />
    );
  })}
</RootStackNavigator.Navigator>
 );
};

export default RootStack;`
```

from redux, you can dispatch an action which would change that condition and this would dynamically update your navigator.

Comment: Yes, I was doing the same way but as per the requirement, I have to show a set of the screen which is in the bottom tab navigation and auth stack when the user clicks on the login button

Comment: Okay, then the only way to make this happen is redux I believe.. I updated an answer with some code example, take a look..